# How Model passes data from client to server in Asp.Net MVC3?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

In ASP.NET when we use `form` it transfer data from client to server using view state.Then how data is transfer from client to server using Model in asp.net MVC3?

What is difference between them?

Comment: I think you should read about model-binding. MVC provides a default model binder artifact that actually can converts your HTTP request into an  Object (the Model) or simply match the signature of your controller's actions. Data is always sent over HTTP verbs.

Answer (score 0):

your question is not clear. if you want to send model data from view to controller then u may make ajax call which post the data on server.

Comment: My question is that if data is pass from client to server using model then how model  hold the data?,If it holds using hidden field then what is difference between  view state and model  hidden filed?

Answer (score 0):

The postback still occurs, although you're using the MVC design, it's still ASP.NET

Typically though, if you're using a model, you pass it as a parameter to your controller, so often you overload your methods in your controller

```
public ActionResult Contact()
{
    //logic
}

[HttpPost]  
public ActionResult Contact(MyModel model)
{
    //logic
}
```

Within that post back, you can call model, or the BLL or DAL as you would expect

```
[HttpPost]  
public ActionResult Contact(MyModel model)
{
    DAL dal = new DAL();
    dal.DoSomeThings(model);
}
```

Of course, it works the other way

```
public ActionResult Contact()
{
    var model = BLL.MyModel();
    return View(model);
}
```